# How to disable mousewheel events in Linux

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to disable MouseWheel event of combobox in some case, so I use below sample code:

```
ttk::combobox .cb -values {a b c} 
bind .cb <MouseWheel> break
pack .cb
```

that code is fine under Windows, but not work in the Linux, and tcl/tk version is same, how to modify it and work fine in the Linux?

Comment: People tell me that MouseWheel is supposed to be a Windows-only event, and that you need to use the extended buttons under X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On X11, mouse wheels are mapped to the (pseudo-)button events `<ButtonPress-4>` and `<ButtonPress-5>` instead of `<MouseWheel>` because there's actually no such event in X11 (unlike on Windows or OSX).

```
if {[tk windowingsystem] eq "x11"} {
    bind .cb <4> break
    bind .cb <5> break
} else {
    bind .cb <MouseWheel> break
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.